# Using Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource in java class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am using Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource to get the property files from the resources folder of the project.The 'filename-message.properties' file is present in classpath of the project.

I don't know what I am missing, somehow the properties file is not picked up.

```
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource= new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames("classpath: filename-message.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I removed ".porperties" from the below code.

```
 ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource= new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames("classpath: filename-message");
```